# Is it possible to add another value to the plotly plot without the axis?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter

I have a requirement, where I need to plot a plotly graph with two axes `x` and `y`. Is it possible to add another parameter to that graph (say `z`) without plotting it in the graph?

For example, if water boils at 100 <sup>o</sup>C at time 5 AM, I want to plot time in `X` and degrees at `Y` and the word 'Water' to be added when hovering over that point.

UPDATE:
In the below image, there are two points of a dataframe being shown when hovered about that point, now I want to know if its possible to add another column of the dataframe to the hover i.e, the column corresponding to 16.3, 621.1 is 300, then I want to show 300 in the hover too, without explicitly plotting it.
[image]

Thanks,

Shyam

Comment: Is [this link](https://plot.ly/python/hover-text-and-formatting/) what you are looking for?

Comment: Not sure. Consider I have three columns in the file. X and Y are plotted along the respective axes and I can see both that values when I hover over it. And now, I want the third column also to be visible when I hover over that, without the column being plotted in the plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely not an elegant solution, but it works:

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

#Create a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({"temp":["100", "15", "95", "90", "85"],
                   "time":["4 AM", "5 AM", "6 AM", "7 AM", "8 AM"],
                   "substance":["Water", "Milk", "Honey", "Beer", "Soda"]})
#Create a lists from DataFrame columns
temp = df["temp"]
time = df["time"]
substance = df["substance"]
#Create an empty list
textlist = []
#Fill this list with info from all of the lists above
for i in [*range(len(temp))]:
    i = temp[i] + "," + time[i] + "," + substance[i] 
    textlist.append(i)
#Set title plot
title = "Boil water"
#Choose in parameter text what you want to see (textlist)
data = [go.Scatter(x = df["time"], 
                   y = df["temp"], 
                   text = textlist,
                   hoverinfo = "text",
                   marker = dict(color = "green"),
                   showlegend = False)]
#Using plotly in offline mode
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)  
#Save plot in directory where your script located without open in browser
plotly.offline.plot({"data": data, "layout": go.Layout(title=title)},
                    auto_open=False, filename = str(title) + ".html")
```

Time on Xaxis, temperature on Yaxis and when you hover onto any of points in graph, you will see something like "100, 4 AM, Water"

Comment: Thanks Oysiyl. Will check this out. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @ShyamV, if you find my solution useful, please, don`t forget check it as answer

Comment: Yes. It works fine. Exactly what I was looking for. Instead of the string, all the variables are float. But thanks for the solution :) Got an idea now.

Answer (score 0):

Ref: https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/#setting-size-and-color-with-column-names

Adding hover_data in the chart will give us the required chart.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).